# Selecionar subcategoria mediante dada categoria

Tags: mysql, sql

Tendo as seguintes tabelas no banco de categoria e subcategoria:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE sub_categories (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  sub_category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY category_key (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

Come seria a SQL para buscar as subcategorias dado o nome de uma categoria? Ex: Selecionar todas as subcategorias da categoria Alimento passando o nome da categoria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode proceder da seguinte forma, Com isto, você conseguirá buscar todos desta categoria:

```
SELECT * FROM sub_categories WHERE categorie_id = '{$id_categoria}'
```

Mas também você pode elaborar da seguinte forma:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_name ASC");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

      $categoria = $row['category_name'];

      echo "<p>CATEGORIA: </p>";
      $sqlSubCategoria = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_categories WHERE categorie_id = '".$row['id']."'");
            while($rowSub=msyqli_fetch_array($sqlSubCategoria)){
                  $subcategoria = $rowSub['sub_category_name'];
                  echo "SUBCATEGORIA: $subcategoria <br>";
            }

}
```

Este exemplo acima busca categoria e subcategoria em forma de lista. Apenas exemplo.

Neste caso você também poderá fazer um SELECT, passando o nome da categoria:

```
SELECT * FROM categories as c, sub_categories as s WHERE c.id = s.category_id AND c.category_name = '{$nomeCategoria}'
```

Comment: mas eu desejo selecionar todas as subcategorias da categoria Alimento. (passando o nome da categoria), editei minha pergunta para ela ficar mais clara.

Comment: Hmmmm e o nome da categoria vem de onde?

Comment: o usuário pode digitar ou posso automaticamente querer listar sistematicamente separando por nome de categoria, mas sempre passando o nome da categoria.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta.